# null termination error in C

Tags: c

I am reading secure coding in C and C++ book by Robert C Seaford.

```
int main(int argv, char* argv[]) {
  char a[16];
  char b[16];
  char c[32];

  strcpy(a, "0123456789abcdef");
  strcpy(b, "0123456789abcdef");
  strcpy(c, a);
  strcat(c, b);
  printf("a = %s\n", a);
  retrun 0;
}
```

The static declarations for the three character arrays fail to allocate storage for null-termination character.

As a result the first `strcpy()` writes a null character beyond the end of the array.

Depending on how the compiler allocates storage, this null byte may be overwritten by the `strcpy()` on next line. If this occurs, `a` now points to an array of 20 characters, while `b` points to an array of 10 characters.

My question is how author mean array `a` contains 20 characters and array `b` points to 10 characters?

Comment: If the author truly said 10 and 20 characters, that author was speaking in hex, which would be 16 and 32 in decimal (and is correct). The author is also making an assumption about how the compiler will place local variables, which may or may not be true. The point is that you must allocate space for your NULLs or you will face undefined results.

Comment: (Not a C guy, so be gentle :p) I thought the hip thing to do these days was to use `strncpy` for reasons like this.

Comment: @KennethK., `strncpy` may not NUL-terminate the destination. So either way you have to pay attention to the amount of memory available at destination. If you _know_ you have enough memory, `strcpy` is all right. If you _know_ you might not have enough memory, you would use `strncpy`. If you don't know either of these, you'd better not program in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to assume that by "10" we are talking about hexadecimal 0x10 (16) and that by "20" we are talking about hexadecimal 0x20 (32).

Anyway the point is that string manipulation code determines the length of the string by the location of the null character, not the number of characters actually allocated in the array.  If memory is allocated like this:

```
<-------a------><-------b------><--------------c-------------->
```

Then after the first `strcpy` the memory looks like this. (I will use ! to indicate the null).

```
<-------a------><-------b------><--------------c-------------->
0123456789abcdef!
```

Then after the second `strcpy` the memory looks like this.

```
<-------a------><-------b------><--------------c-------------->
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef!
```

Each `strcpy` operation is overflowing the array it's supposed to be writing into and using adjacent memory, a very bad practice.  And any function that manipulates `a` like it's a string will see 32 (0x20) characters (not counting the null) and any function that manipulates `b` like it's a string will see 16 (0x10) characters (not counting the null) - despite the fact that you've only allocated enough memory in each array for 15 characters (not counting the null).

The fact that any of this doesn't crash is an accident of how the memory is being laid out.  If you write more characters into an array than you have space for, and the adjacent memory being written into isn't writable, then you will crash.

And of course, since you're reading about secure coding, the fact that you're overwriting something else could be a serious security problem depending on how trusted the input is and exactly what is getting overwritten.